# How to avoid duplicate data insert in MS SQL using Unique Key number from response?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

if 10 elements saved in sql server with unique number and response reached to 12 element with increment time to time. when i insert data the whole data will inserted and data element reached 22 elements.
i want only 12th element inserted in database. Please help me out of this.

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you are doing?

Comment: actually i have response from another server , i saved that response in my sql table through query, but when response increased then all data were saved again and data duplication held. i need a query of sql where i insert only updated data. Thanks

Comment: Your question at its current state is only understandable to you.You will need to add some examples and show more info.Below link contains good example on how to start asking:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/